# Proof for the application XYZ is never installed on a non-rooted Android phone

Tags: applications, uninstallation

With adb, we can list the applications. In the documentation, the `-u` option also lists the uninstalled applications. I'd tested and this is not working!

I need at least one way to prove or at least convince someone that in a non-rooted Android phone the XYZ application is never installed!

Comment: There may be residue from that app's temporary files or cache on the internal storage but if you reset the phone, all information about this is wiped. If the app was installed through the Google Play Store, there might be an entry left in My Apps -> All, however, it can be easily removed.

Comment: Does Google keep an audit, at least for statistics?

Comment: Once it's removed, it's gone. If that app, however, offers to log in with your Google account, that entry about the app's access to your account is kept separately in your third-party accesses (this doesn't track the device, though)

Comment: There is the [Avast Fronsic](https://blog.avast.com/2014/07/09/android-foreniscs-pt-2-how-we-recovered-erased-data/), but it is not %100 and may require experts.

Comment: Yeah, I'd say if it's not in your Google Play "All" list, then it's *plausibly* never been installed. However, this would not alone constitute *proof*. It sucks that you have to prove a negative though, it should be up to this person to prove the app was ever installed!

Comment: Does Google Play list the third party apps?